# can't modify frozen Hash in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm getting the following error,

```
can't modify frozen Hash
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ui/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_r
ecord/attribute_methods/write.rb:38:in `[]='
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ui/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_r
ecord/attribute_methods/write.rb:38:in `write_attribute'
```

from this line

```
write_attribute(:value, new_value)
```

This can be run properly for certain days. But, now it fail continously with an above error. I tried out solution for that but nothing work for me.

Comment: is the object destroyed?

Comment: yes, some of the objects can destroyed.

Comment: then you have your answer

Comment: You cannot update attributes on destroyed objects. You need to check if its destroyed or not before you do your stuff.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As explained in comments, you cannot update attributes on destroyed objects.

Check with something like:

```
write_attribute(:value, new_value) unless destroyed?
```

Comment: Its working fine for me. But, if the condition fails the above error must return. how i overcome this?\

Comment: I can't see any other reason why it could happen

Comment: Of course there is a Model.destroyed? method, I should have known.